# How do I know when a directive is called in submit btn?

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I'm looking for a way to tell when a directive is called when I click the submit button.

I have a directive that listens when a user selects a keyboard short cut.

How am I able to tell if the short cut was triggered using the directive?

```
//Directive
@Directive({
   selector: [shortcut]
})
export class shortCutDirective{
    @HostListener('window:keyup', ['event'])
    if(event.keyCode == 32){
       console.log('short cut triggered');
    }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `      
      <ng-template>
          <form ngSubmit = login() [shortcut]> 
              <button type = submit>
                      <span>Login </span>
              </button>
      </ng-template>
  `})
export class AppComponent {
    login() {
        console.log('Login');
    }

    loginByShortCutMethod() {
        console.log('Short cut was used');
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using HostListener()?. Kindly share some code snippet or a minimum stackblitz setup so the community can help you. Share something what you have done so far?

Comment: Thank you @WahabShah  - I'm new to the forum. I've added a sample code

Comment: You are welcome. Currently you are checking it on spacebar right? keycode == 32. Just for testing purposes  make it on click or hover to see its console.log. And also just try using the attribute, remove the square brackets like this, `<form ngSubmit = login()  shortcut>`

Comment: awesome! That worked! Thank you

Comment: You are welcome. :). I will put it up as answer as well, Mark it so that it helps someone in future.

Comment: I have just added it as an answer now.

Comment: Thank you again :)

Comment: My pleasure :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you are checking with spacebar, right? keycode == 32. Just for testing purposes make it on click or hover to see its console logging or not.

And also just use the attribute with name no binding, remove the square brackets, like the following:

`<form ngSubmit = login()  shortcut>`